# Parallel processing in R - why more cores takes more time?

Tags: r, multithreading, doparallel

I did a test where I parallelized 1000 jobs to N cores using mclapply in R (code below). I got some strange result, where up to a point (~40 cores), more cores speed up the process, but from that point it actually takes more time with more cores. What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Nitzan

[Number of cores (x-axis) as a function of time (y-axis)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5C87.png)

Here is the code I used where 'myfunction' is some reinforcement learning model

```
for (i in 1:12){
mycores[i]=96-8*(i-1)
print(mycores)
start_time <- Sys.time()

df<-
lapply(1:3,     function(X){
lapply(1:10,    function(Y){
mclapply(1:1000,function(Z){
myfunction(X,Y,Z),
mc.cores=mycores[i])})})

mytime[i]= Sys.time() - start_time
}
```

Comment: There is a cost to starting up a new thread. If the code you are running runs very fast, then it's possible the setup/teardown time will dominate. Also, how many cores do you actually have on your machine? Are there other processes running on your machine?If you are competing with other programs for cores you'll lose time when different threads are swapped out.

Comment: Classic parallelization overhead, in your specific case possibly from copying data to the workers. Also, you should always (with very few exceptions) parallelize the outermost loop.